# Core razor beginform html tag wrong

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Good afternoon,

I am working on a simple form in ASP.NET Core 3.1, and I am struggling to understand beginform.

I have a search box on one page (in this case /Index), and using GET (a requirement) when someone types their search in and presses the search button, the Action needs to go off to another page (in this case /Listing )

In the razor form page, if I use : -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Listing", "", FormMethod.Get))
{
}
```

..... but I get this HTML created : -

```
<form action="/?action=Listing" method="get">
</form>
```

What I would expect to see is : -

```
<form method="get" action="/Listing">
</form>
```

So what am I doing wrong with my BeginForm above to be getting the wrong HTML created for the  tag please?

I have tried numerous answers found elsewhere but they are for MVC and I am using Razor pages only not MVC.

Thank you in adavnce if you can help?

Harry

Answer (score 1):

`Html.BeginForm` is the older way from MVC. It's parameters are Action and Controller e.g.

```html
Html.BeginForm("AddNewCustomer", "Customer", FormMethod.Post)
```

Posts to `CustomerController` calling the `AddNewCustomer` method.

If you are using the new Razor pages then you write the html directly and add attributes that start with `asp-`.

e.g. [Build a Form in Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/#write-a-basic-form)

If you want to set the page where the form posts to the `Listing.cshtml` page would look like this:

```html
<form method="get" asp-page="./Listing">
</form>
```

Note that asp-page is a path to a Razor page file relative to the current file. Not a Url link.